Should we be using auto incrementing indexes as foreign keys in T-SQL?
I believe we've hit a fundamental design problem in our database which I will try to summarise as best I can.
We frequently add to our production databases with more data from a master "default" DB which we are routinely adding to. This data can be considered a kind of feature for users. These deployments can happen as frequently as after every three week sprint.
We are using auto incrementing ints as the PK on parent tables, and that is the FK on child tables.
The problem is that users can add to these tables, therefore incrementing the ids, so that when we come to import new data at the end of a sprint we are forced to reindex.
For example:
Table Kingdoms has columns id (pk) and kingdom with data:

1, Fish
2, Mammals

Table Animals has columns id (pk), kingdom_id (fk) and animal with data:

1, 1, Tuna
2, 2, Dog
3, 2, Cat

In a typical deployment we might want to add a new "Kingdom" as a feature. So we would import from the default database the new Kingdom, which would have id 3, "Reptiles". It would also have id 4 "Lizard" on the Animals table.
The problem is that in between deployments the users might have added more fish and mammals to the DB so the "4" id is taken.
I feel like we have gone about this in fundamentally the wrong way, and would appreciate some advice. Either we shouldn't be using auto-incrementing ints or we need a different approach to migration.
On previous projects with similar requirements I have implemented UUIDs as a unique non-primary key to use as the foreign key on other tables instead (I am not the DB admin on this project). UUIDs are random and so wouldn't have collisions with new data. I've been told this is not so efficient though.
Alternatively, it might be that we're going about migrating the data the wrong way. I think that we should have a process to import it programmatically, rather than the "lift and shift" we're currently doing.

Nobody should care what the pk or fk values are. if you need an ID number to associate with the Kingdom or animal then make another ID column. Users should never know a numeric pk or fk even exists.

You are going about this problem the wrong way.  SQL is a set-based language.  It does not care about order for most of what it does, but it can do things in an order in a query.  So, if you have an auto-incrementing field and you want to get things in order like this, you probably should consider ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PK)

Can you use separate tables for user and "master" data and then join them together when displaying it to user? is there some feedback on the master data like editing etc

It sounds like you will need a custom database merge process that creates and uses a PK mapping for each table. One table at a time, starting with lookup tables with no dependencies and working down the dependency tree, the logic would (1) apply an appropriate rule (different for each table) to match source and target rows, (2) assign new distinct target pk mappings for any unmatched source PKs, and (3) copy the unmatched rows, mapping all PKs and FKs in the process. For those rows that do match, you would need to decide which data to keep if some columns in those  rows differ.

If you switched your PKs to GUIDs, you would possibly still need a similar PK matching and mapping process, since users on both instances might enter the same data, which would be assigned different IDs.  A third possibility exists if your master/default database only contains relatively fixed lookup data such as statuses or city/state/zip data. You could reserve a range of PK values for master use only and initialize the PK IDENTITY insert values start 10 or 1000 times higher than you would ever expect to use in your master/default data. You might still need to dedup after a merge.

@BartMcEndree thank you. For clarity, the users never see the PK ids. There is a non unique "display id" for them. The issue is more about mappings. The app has a lot of functions for mapping different forms of data in order to drive reports. The reports are the output. We maintain and update a library of "Kingdoms" and "Animals" and other things (Sorry for the juvenile example) which is part of the service. The user can also add to this library themselves. The issue is that even if they don't see the PK id, they're creating new ones by using the app which might conflict with our updates.

@ConorCunninghamMSFT thank you. We aren't concerned with ordering data. In the front end we have custom ways of ordering it for the users.

@siggemannen thank you. I think I wasn't clear in the post. The default DB is totally separate. We have a single tenanted infrastructure where each client has their own DB. I suppose the crux of the problem is how to manage migrating new data from the default DB into the several client DBs, since they obviously start diverging as soon as people start using them. To answer your question directly, we do mark each row as "custom" or not.

@TN thank you for your response. To be honest that is basically what we are currently doing. But in this morning's stand up the DB admin said that one of these migration processes will take 2.5 hours. We currently have 8 production DBs, and are adding 2 new DBs a month. I can't help but think we're doing this all wrong as this shouldn't be so onerous.

@TN on your second comment, that's actually a good idea. Thank you. I'm going to raise it with our DB admin in our follow up call. The data isn't static lookup data, but setting the starter id at 9999 or something would shield us from this problem for the foreseeable future at least.

I would hope that in your "master data" tables and your target DB tables, you also have UNIQUE indexes on the "name" field of the entity. So, for example, you cannot add "Fish" twice to the Kingdom table. Then, you'd only need to insert into the target DB all the values from the master DB where "name" doesn't exist. You'll have no issues with the numerical PK being different between databases.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
